# silverlight + wcf deployment - development port interferes

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight 5 application, with a (non RIA) WCF service in my web project.
Of course it works great on my machine ;-) - Windows 7, but when I deploy it to my dev server (a WinServer2008 with .NET 4 on it, using IIS 6), the application doesnt seem to finish loading - I get the initial silverlight Loading... then I just have a blank screen. I dont see any error messages.

I think the issue may be that the silveright app assumes that the port for the WCF service is the same as it was on my machine (46133).

Ive seen articles online that say that you should set the address of the endpoint in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig to ../Service.svc. If I change it to this, and deploy, nothing changes.

In the properties of the web project, on the web tab, I have Use Visual Studio Development Server checked, and specific port 46133, Virtual Path =/

I think that the deployed site, is still trying to use port 46133, because Fiddler shows a 502 red item for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file, with the message

[Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:46133

Any suggestions?

Here's the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="../Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My web.config is

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpStreamingBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
            <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client />

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
      <service name="CitationAir.MissionPlanning.WebService.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpStreamingBinding"
            contract="CitationAir.MissionPlanning.WebService.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but I dont see an address or a base address for the service to listen to. I'm new to WCF also, but I believe when you deploy to the production server, it should have one, and the client config needs to look that that also in the address. I think fiddler result is based off your client config setting that I see as "../Service.svc", which is probably why you see the localhost stuff. Try setting the server and client config to the same thing in the deployment server.

Comment: If your deployment service is at abc.com, try setting both the service and the client address to: http : // www.abc.com/Service.svc (assuming your service is at the root, without the spaces, stackoverflow is turning that into a link sorry).

Comment: It is configured in the project settings on the web page: In the properties of the web project, on the web tab, I have Use Visual Studio Development Server checked, and specific port 46133, Virtual Path =/

Comment: The ability to add relative address in the ServiceReferences.clientconfig was added for just the thing I'm trying to avoid. The ../Service.svc is in relation to the XAP file's location.